# Flask and sqlite3 - does a table need to be populated with data before the 'insert into' sql command can work?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, flask, insert

When creating a flask site with sqlite3, I noticed that if I tried to INSERTINTO (using a web-form) the database, when the database was empty, it wouldn't produce an error, but nothing would happen, the INSERT INTO (SQL) would simply not take effect.

I had to manually populate the database using a pre-made query, and then, without changing anything else in the code, the inserting-into the form worked fine.

Can anyone shed any light as to why this might have happened? I assume it isn't necessary for a database to be populated in order for it to be used/functional in flask/sqlite3.

I wondered if it had anything to do with my setup.

**create-db.py**

```
import sqlite3
db_locale='users.db' #flask will create this db if it doesn't exist

connie=sqlite3.connect(db_locale)
c=connie.cursor() #used to create commands


c.execute("""

CREATE TABLE comments
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    name TEXT,
    comments TEXT
)

    """)

connie.commit()
connie.close()
```

**The addcomment() and insertcomment() methods in the main .py file**

```
def addcomment():
    if request.method=="GET":
        return render_template('addcomment.html')
    else:
        user_details=(
            request.form['title'],
            request.form['name'],
            request.form['comments']

            )
        insertcomment(user_details)
        return render_template('addsuccess.html')


def insertcomment(user_details):
    connie=sqlite3.connect(db_locale)
    c=connie.cursor()
    sql_execute_string='INSERT INTO comments (title,name,comments) VALUES (?,?,?)';
    c.execute(sql_execute_string,user_details)
    connie.commit()
    connie.close()
    print(user_details)
```

Comment: Odd behavior. Query should work on empty table. My guess is try reproducing this behavior. Maybe you missed something?

Comment: Does the sqlite3 database exist as a file *before* append? Ideally, all database tables and schemas are developed before flask app is run. As planned resources, relational databases should not be designed on the fly. DDL statements like `CREATE` or `ALTER` should rarely be run in code if at all but one-time calls in database's admin shell or CLI.